# React: Splash screen/container

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: Example of Container]

Currently I have a page with a container set up as above, with a small game running inside it and a bar which keeps the score/time taken to complete a task within a game.

I am wanting to build a sort of splash screen that displays initially when you start the game, and maybe allows you to change a few options such as whether to use Addition/Subtraction etc.

I am quite new to React so I'm not sure I fully understand how everything works with rendering but how would I build this so that the container does not render again but can change between the splash and the game itself. My code in the render part so far is:

```
 render() {
    return (
      <section className="arithmetic">
        <div className="arithmetic__game">
          <div className="row arithmetic__row--details">
            <div className="arithmetic__score">
            Score:&nbsp;&nbsp;{this.state.score}
            </div>
            <div className="arithmetic__timer">
              <Timer onRef={ref => (this.timer = ref)} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row arithmetic__row--main">
            <div className="arithmetic__examples">
              1 + 1 = 2<br/>
              2 + 1 = 3<br />
            </div> 
            <div className="arithmetic__game-container">
            What is {this.state.numbers.x} + {this.state.numbers.y}?
              <div className="arithmetic__form-container">
                <form className="main-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <label>
                    Answer: &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input className="input-field" type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                  </label>
                  <button className="btn-submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
};
```

I was thinking of having the two views in separate files but that means moving out a lot of dependent functions which just seems like it would create a big mess.

**EDIT:** Also, should I be using refs to manipulate state etc from the parent class?

Answer (score 0):

The most readable way would be to create a component for the Splashscreen, like this. Notice that I'm setting the style for the component in its own function to prevent unnecessary re-renders.

```
export default class SplashScreen extends React.Component {
    renderSplash() {
        let splashStyle = {
            height: "100vh", 
            width: "100vw", 
            display: "flex", 
            justifyContent: "center", 
            alignItems: "center"
        }
        return(
            <div style={splashStyle}>
                <h1>SPLASH SCREEN</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return this.renderSplash()
    }
}
```

Then in your parent component you need to set a state for handling the logic. Suppose your class is App then it should look something like this:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          showSplash: true //this is the initial state
        }
    }

    renderApp() {
        return (
            {*/ Your code here /*}
        )
    }

    render() {
        {this.state.showSplash ? <SplashScreen /> : this.renderApp()}
    }
}
```

Notice that I'm dividing everything in functions. It makes it easy to switch between states/components in cases like this.

I don't know how you want to show the splash, if you want it deactivated once data is loaded or some timer function, but I'll update this answer with a few tips if you'd like.

Comment: The fact that you are setting the styles in a separate method that is called by the render method actually has no effect on re-renders.

Comment: This is a bad example unfortunately, but I want to stress for newcomers that it's a good idea to keep styles and such separate from the regular life cycle methods. If the style is based on a state then it will trigger unnecessary re-renders. But you are 100% correct in this case.

Comment: If styles depend on state then you need the re-render anyway. I think the proper way would be using StyleSheet.create or a simple CSS class. That will not save you re-renders, but avoids object creation on each render (not that it's something you need to care about too much).

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to expand the application in the future and add more pages/screens you might consider using `react-router` which takes a bit to set up but after that makes switching screens much easier.

There are quite a lot of tutorials and examples involving `react-router` here:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/

Comment: I have my react-router index.js page to route files that change the main view, but I was wanting to change a view within a view sort of thing, without changing the URL. Is this possible?